# Почему этот код удаляет содержимое файла?

Tags: java

Запускаю программу: *java Main Tetst.txt*
Содержимое файла удаляется.

```
import java.io.*;

public class Main {
public static void main(String args[]){
    int i;
    char string [];
    FileInputStream fin;
    FileOutputStream fos;
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String str;
    String name_file = args[0];
    if (args.length!=1){
        System.out.println(args[0]);
        return;
    }

    try{
        fin = new FileInputStream(name_file);
        fos = new FileOutputStream(name_file);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e){
        System.out.println("Невозможно открыть файл");
        return;
    }

    try{
        do{
            i = fin.read();
            if(i!=-1)System.out.print((char) i);
        } while (i !=-1);
    } catch (IOException e){
        System.out.println("Ошибка чтения из файла");
    }
    try {
        do {
            str = br.readLine();
            string = str.toCharArray();
            if (!str.equalsIgnoreCase("Exit")) {
                for (int j = 0; j < str.length(); j++) {
                    fos.write(string[j]);
                }
            }
        } while (!str.equalsIgnoreCase("Exit"));
    }catch (IOException e){
      System.out.println("Ошибка чтения / записи");
    } finally {
        try{
            fin.close();
        }catch (IOException e){
            System.out.println("Ошибка закрытия файла");
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно сделать что-то похожее на это:

```
//параметр №2 указывает, что данные будут дописыаться в существующий файл
//а не будет создаваться новый
FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file, true);

PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(fileWriter);
BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(printWriter);
bufferedWriter.write("Hello");
```

Comment: Теперь, ясно почему файл был пустым, спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

Чтобы **добавить** содержимое используйте следующий конструктор:

```
FileOutputStream(String name, boolean append)
```

с параметром `append` равным `true`.

Comment: Да, спасибо. Это есть решение.

Answer (score 2):

Используйте этот конструктор для *дозаписи* в файл

*FileOutputStream(File file, boolean append)* 
Creates a file output stream to write to the file represented by the specified File object.

```
File file = File("test.txt");
FileOtputStream f = new FileOutputStream(file, true);
```

Comment: Да я понял надо удалить коментарии

Comment: Использование этого конструктора решает проблему. Спасибо. Я правильно понял, что если не указывать параметр append то файл создается заново?

Comment: @MStupnitsky почти, содержимое файла удаляется и записывается новое, происходит перезапись. А сам файл не удаляется ;)